# Swagger2 not dispaying the documentation is UI format

Tags: spring, swagger, spring-rest, springfox

I have `RESTful` web service which I have developed in spring boot. I have integrated the `swagger2` in my application using `Gradle` build tool.

```
testCompile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.6.1')
testCompile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.6.1')
```

I wrote the configuration file for `swagger2` in following way

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.restdemo.web"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Now when I try to access the `http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs` I am getting the `JSON` string. But when I am trying to access the `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` I am not getting Swagger UI view, I am getting the `406` error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below Swagger configurations? basePackage is nothing but the entry point of your rest API layer. You can hardcode it in your program.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
        return new UiConfiguration("validatorUrl", "list", "alpha", "schema",
                UiConfiguration.Constants.DEFAULT_SUBMIT_METHODS, false, true, 60000L);
    }

}
```

Comment: even I was having this issue. You mean `@Value("${xyz.abc.myPackage}")`

Comment: You have to pass the base package to apis. For my case, there were several microservices, so I made it configurable, if you have only one service just pass the base package to .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(<basePackage name>))

Comment: Updated the answer. Could you please try this config along with whatever you have

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this?
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html#!/test-controller/

Here Controller class name is TestController

Also, replace

.select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.restdemo.web"))

with

.select()

As below..

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
}
```